# Manually start processes from python pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have managed to make a pool, limit it to run only 2 processes at a time.

```
process_pool = Pool(2)
commands = []
for (dirpath, dir, file) in os.walk("files"):
    for name in file:
        command = "python process.py {0}".format(name)
        commands.append(command)

for i, returncode in enumerate(process_pool.imap(partial(call, shell=False), commands)):
   if returncode != 0:
      print("command {0} failed".format(i))


def check_limit():
    pgrep = subprocess.Popen("pgrep subprocess".split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
    wc = subprocess.Popen("wc -l".split(), stdin=pgrep.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
    return wc.communicate()[0]
```

It is all done automatically, when the process terminates the new one is started in his place. Is there any way to controll them manually?

Processing binary spawns up to additional 20 subprocesses with limit of 350MB of RAM per process and global limit 60 subprocesses per machine. The parent process terminates when all subprocesses terminate, then the pool starts another parent process - which is not an optimal solution in this case. As the subprocesses are asynchronous, some of them might terminate earlier that other and I would like to start another parent process so it can start spawning new children.
It might look something like this.

```
start process
if subprocesses < 60
    start process
else 
    wait 10 secs
```

Here is the same thing done in bash.

```
for i in `ls -1 $PATH/*xml`; do
    COMMAND="${BINPATH} ${i}"
    if [ $BACKGROUND -eq 1 ]; then
        check_limit
        $COMMAND >> $LogFile 2>&1 &

    PIDLIST="$! ${PIDLIST}"
done
pwait ${PIDLIST} >& /dev/null
```

Is tere any way to acchieve this, maybe Pool is not the best solution here and I should use Queue?

Answer (score 0):

Stack overflow sometimes works as a rubber duck, while waiting for a help I have solved this issue myself. Simply removed waiting for subprocess.Popen result and wraped it up in while loop

```
command_counter = 0
while True:
    file = open(INPUT_FILE)
    if check_child_processes() < 60 and command_counter < len(commands_list):
        subprocess.Popen(commands_list[command_counter].split(), shell=False, stdin=file)
        command_counter += 1
    time.sleep(1)
    if check_parent_processes() == 0:
        break
```

Anyway thanks for help.